# use common defaults in backbone.js from many views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I use backbone.js with require.js and have one parent view and two child views.

I want to have common defaults in ParentModel, have common logic to control defaults in ParentView and call ParentView logic from children views.
code is here.

parentView.js

```
 define(
  ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'models/parentModel'],
  function($, _, Backbone, ParentModel) {

    var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
      model: new ParentModel(),
      initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("change:hoge", this.switchHoge);
      },
      parentSet: function(k, v) {
        // context is childen model
        // want to set parent model
        this.model.set(k, v);
      },
      switchHoge: function(k, v) {
        if (this.model.get("view") == "A") {
          console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaa");
        } else if (this.model.get("view") == "B") {
          console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbb");
        }
      }
    });

    return ParentView;
  }
);
```

childView_A

```
  var ChildView_A = ParentView.extend({
    model: new ChildModel_A(),
    change: function() {
      this.parentSet("hoge", "A");
    }
  }
```

childView_B.js

```
var ChildView_B = ParentView.extend({
  model: new ChildModel_B(),
  change: function() {
    this.parentSet("hoge", "B");
  }
});
```

It is problem that parentSet context is replaced by children model.
So function which binded in ParentView is not called.

If I rename ParentView:model to ParentView:another_model, I could resolve this problem.

But it seems not beautiful.

Is this badpractice in Backbone.js?
What shold I do?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you could reference your parent's view when you create the new child view like this:

```
var Parent = new ParentView({model: model});

var Child_A = new ChildView_A({parent: Parent});
```

And then in your chieldview you can do:

```
this.options.parent.parentSet("hoge", "A");
```

And that should call the method with the context of your parent view.

You could also add in the initialization method of your child view this line to make it easier to access your parent view:

```
this.parentView = this.options.parent;
```

Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5JRZe/2/

Answer (score 0):

You're listening to change event without giving it context -- therefore `this` inside `change` is not a view instance.  To fix change your event subscription code as follows:

```
this.model.on("change:hoge", this.switchHoge, this);
```

Actually, it's always good idea to pass `this` as a context to event listeners -- unless you specifically want something else there and in my practice it rarely happens.